# the number of ways of holding tickets in an express train

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $10$ intermediary stations between $2$ junctions where an express train stops. If $6$ passengers board the train at some intermediary station or other during their journey and each of the $6$ passengers hold a different variety of ticket of the same class, then find the number of ways in which they can hold their tickets?

MY ATTEMPT: If a particular ticket is unique and is determined by the source and destination, then; There are 10 sources and 10
destinations, hence no of different tickets will be $(10+9+8⋯⋯+1)=55$

So the different sets of tickets which they  can have will be $^{55} C _6$,  but the given answer is $^{55} P _6$

What am I missing out on?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the question.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What do you mean by " a different variety of ticket of the same class" ??

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I'm really sorry but I'm new to the site. will keep that in mind from the next time

Comment: @trueblueanil it basically means they hold a unique ticket... that's the language of the question

Comment: Isn't there a $6$ somewhere in the question ?

Comment: $6$ pasengers for goodness sake !

Comment: Well, then don't you have to distribute tickets to them ?

Comment: What true blue anil is saying is that once you have selected the source and destination of each ticket, you have to choose which passenger receives which ticket.

Comment: oh got it my bad!

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think I need to explain in some detail, you need to distinguish clearly between combinations and permutations.

$^{55}C_6$ here means dividing  $55$ different tickets into $6$ bunches.

But they have to be given to $6$ distinct *people* (people are inherently distinct) and you don't know who holds which variety of ticket, so you need to multiply by $6!$

And you do know that $^{55}P_6$ = $^{55}C_6*6!$

Comment: You are wecome ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: that was such a silly error though

Comment: No sweat ! I am not able to count how many silly errors I have made at various times !

Answer (score 2):

Passenger A chooses a ticket from $55$.

Passenger B chooses a ticket from $54$.

etc...

Passenger F chooses a ticket from $50$.

$$55\cdot54\cdot53\cdot52\cdot51\cdot50=\frac{55!}{49!}=\frac{55!}{(55-6)!}=\;^{55}P_6$$